# PL SQL Execute Immediate not working when calling it from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have created the following SP

```
create or replace PROCEDURE RM_SUPPORT_SCRIPTS_V2 
(
              V_TABLENAME IN USER_TABLES.table_name%type
            , V_SETCOLNAME IN NVARCHAR2 
            , V_SETVALUE IN NVARCHAR2 
            , V_WHERECOLNAME IN NVARCHAR2 
            , V_WHEREKEYVALUE IN NVARCHAR2 
            , USER_ID IN NVARCHAR2 
    ) 
    IS 
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
        'UPDATE '||DBMS_ASSERT.simple_sql_name(V_TABLENAME) 
            ||' SET :1 = :2, update_by_userid = :3, UPDATE_DATE = SYSDATE'
            ||' WHERE :4 = :5 '
            using V_SETCOLNAME, V_SETVALUE, USER_ID, V_WHERECOLNAME, V_WHEREKEYVALUE; 
    
END RM_SUPPORT_SCRIPTS_V2;
```

But when I call it from an EXECUTE statement

```
EXEC RM_SUPPORT_SCRIPTS_V2 (USERS_TABLE, USER_ID,ORTEGALUX,USER_ID,TESTED,FX);
```

I get the following error

> Error report -
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 31:
> PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'USERS_TABLE' not allowed in this context
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action:

Does anyone know why this could be happening? I have tried putting simple comma in the call of each table, column but continue failing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is coming from the call, not the procedure. You're passing strings so you need to quote them:

```
EXEC RM_SUPPORT_SCRIPTS_V2 ('USERS_TABLE', 'USER_ID','ORTEGALUX','USER_ID','TESTED','FX');
```

But you can't use bind variables for column names, you need to concatenate those in, as you are with the table name.

```
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
        'UPDATE '||DBMS_ASSERT.simple_sql_name(V_TABLENAME) 
            ||' SET ' || V_SETCOLNAME || ' = :1, update_by_userid = :2, UPDATE_DATE = SYSDATE'
            ||' WHERE ' || V_WHERECOLNAME || ' = :3 '
            using V_SETVALUE, USER_ID, V_WHEREKEYVALUE;
```

though you may want to add assertion checks for those too.

Comment: Thank you @Alex Poole I have tried quoting as you informed but I'm now getting this error  `code` Error starting at line : 1 in command -
BEGIN RM_SUPPORT_SCRIPTS_V2 ('user_list', 'USERS_TABLE','ORTEGALUX','USER_ID','TESTED','FX'); END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 316:
PLS-00201: identifier 'RM_SUPPORT_SCRIPTS_V2' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 316:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: You changed RM to FMV? That doesn't seem to exist...?

Comment: Well, does it actually exist? In the same schema you are calling it from? (And does the error really refer to column 316? That seems odd.}

Comment: You were right, I was in a wrong schema now I get this ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
ORA-06512: at "OPTIMA.RM_SUPPORT_SCRIPTS_V2", line 12
ORA-06512: at line 1
01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

Comment: UPDATE, I have the script with different tables and the error persists.

Comment: The OPTIMA user needs to grant execute permission on the procedure to the user who is trying to call it.